# play sound on receiver phone when message from custom app is send

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am building android app where i need to send message to some contacts and that receive must read that message immediately.I want to play some music when i send message from my app at receivers place even if his mobile is in silent mode.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If I have my phone in silent mode, I really don't want to hear a sound from any kind of app... I'm pretty sure that android will never let you do this. (Maybe I'm wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Google Cloud Messanging or a service wich does Poling on the server looking for new messages.

the first one is better.
On message received create a notification that plays a sound and shows the message.

If the receiver keeps the device with no sound, you shouldn't force it to play the sound